# RTK Query - Dispatch action after mutation in form submission

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, rtk-query

so I am just learning RTK query and I am trying to just dispatch an action after I run a mutation hook in a form. My code looks like this:

```
const Login = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const [postCredentials, { isSuccess }] = useLoginMutation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
    await postCredentials({
      username: data.username,
      password: data.password,
    });
    console.log('RESULT', isSuccess);

    // {
    //   isSuccess && dispatch(setUserStatus({ isLoggedIn: true }));
    // }
  };
---------------
```

When I submit the form it does post to the end point and responds successfully(network tab in Chrome dev tools). My problem is that after the `await postCredentials()` function the `console.log(isSuccess)` is false even after I know the POST is successful. If I click again then the `console.log(isSuccess)` is true. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I expect the `isSuccess` to be true first time around so I can then dispatch a new action. TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a stale reference here.

See this example:

```
let a = 0
function MyComponent(){
  const b = a
  function increment(){
    console.log(b)
    a++
    console.log(b)
  }
  useEffect(increment)
}
```

`foo` is your component. No matter how much you change `a` here, `b` is a copy of it and will not change. If you run the function again (which is what a component rerender would do), there will be a new variable called `b` within the scope of that new execution - and there will also be a new *function* called `increment` within the scope of that new execution. That "new" `increment" can read the "new value" of` b`, but will again not get any update to *that*.

So: `isSuccess` will never change within one execution of your `onSubmit` method.

What you can do instead is `unwrap` the result:

```
const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
  try {
    const result = await postCredentials({
      username: data.username,
      password: data.password,
    }).unwrap();
    console.log('RESULT', result);
    dispatch(setUserStatus({ isLoggedIn: true }));
  } catch (e) {
  }
  };
```

All that said, there is also another solution: don't use `setUserStatus` at all.

Add a listener for the `api.endpoints.postCredentials.matchFulfilled` case to your user status slice's `extraReducers`. That way whenever `postCredetials` executes successfully, that slice can react to it and change accordingly.